# Hide Scroll Indicator in native toolbar

Tags: swiftui

How can the scroll indicator be hidden in SwiftUI when using the native toolbar?

```
.toolbar {
           ToolbarItem(placement: .navigation) {
              Menu {
```

Comment: I don't get it. What is relevant between the scroll indicator and the toolbar?  How about `ScrollView(showsIndicators: false)`?

Comment: @son I tried that before, I didn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you share more code where the scrollView was implemented? Or at least a screenshot? Those lines above did nothing on scrollView.